# Почему calc превращает отрицательное число повторений в одно?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid, css-math

Почему в Хроме (версия 121 и не только) `repeat(-10, 1fr)` является ошибкой, а `repeat(calc(-10), 1fr)` ведёт себя как 1? С другими неположительными числами - аналогично. Я ожидал, что поведение будет одинаковым...

[image: скриншот]

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: antiquewhite;
  display: grid;
  padding: .5em;
  gap: .5em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.a {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(-10, 1fr) 1fr;
}

.b {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(calc(-10), 1fr) 1fr;
}

div {
  height: 1em;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<section class="a">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>

<section class="b">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Стоит заметить, что `calc(любое не положительное число)` считается за 1. Это может  быть `0`, `-100`, `-7895665`...

Comment: это уже вопрос к тому браузеру которым пользуетесь(и его движку конечно же), а не к самому `calc`, в FF 91 оба варианта игнорируются как ошибочные. вообще, вопреки спекам, в FF он мало на что пригоден кроме работы с габаритами. например даже такая банальность `... :after{content: calc(1)}` тоже выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @eccs0103, только в repeat. Ну а то, что любое - да, я думал, это очевидно.

Comment: @puffleeck, в FF я не проверил. Мне для того, что я задумал, нужна была ошибка, а Хром решил, что это единица... А что касается `content: calc(1)` - это и есть ошибка - в content нельзя числа писать, только строки. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42532945/4928642

Comment: Нагуглил таки: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#calc-range результат calc принудительно приводится к допустимому значению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#calc-range

> Parse-time range-checking of values is **not performed within math functions**, and therefore out-of-range values do not cause the declaration to become invalid. However, the value resulting from a top-level calculation must be **clamped to the range allowed in the target context**.

Для математических функций (в частности `calc`) не происходит проверка на соответствие ограничениям в процессе парсинга, но результат вычисления принудительно вписывается в ограничения.

В вашем примере у `repeat()` первое значение должно быть целым положительным числом (`<integer [1,∞]>`) поэтому число `-10` приводится к ближайшему разрешённому, т.е. `1`.

При этом для явно заданных значений ([specified value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#specified-value)) такого принудительного вписывания не происходит и всё объявленное просто становится невалидным и игнорируется.

Там же в документации приведён простой пример: `width: -5px` невалидно и браузер игнорирует это правило, а в `width: calc(-5px);` приводится к ближайшему разрешённому значению и получается `width: 0px;`

Comment: Ну вот... А так хотелось это использовать как костыль вместо container style query... Отличный ответ!